# Client side encryption in AWSS3 in iOS using AWS KMS CMK

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I Have managed to do the `server side encryption` in `Amazon S3` with my `AWS KMS` master key. So my questions is, How to do `client side encryption` in `Amazon S3` in iOS using `AWS KMS` **customer master key**?

Thanks in advance for your help!